# SQL Multiple rows but one expected

Tags: sql

I've got the following query with joins:

```
SELECT i.PropertyCodeId, i.IndividualCode, i.LastName, 
       i.Firstname, i.AccountCode, acc.Name AS AccountName,
       (SELECT value 
        FROM Relation.ContactDetail AS cd 
        WHERE cd.ContactDetailTypeCode = 'EMAIL' 
              AND cd.RelationCode = i.IndividualCode) AS Email,
       adr.City, adr.ZipCode, adr.StateCode, adr.CountryCode, 
       'undefined' AS MemberShipID, i.TierCode AS MemberShipTier,
       i.VipCode, i.Active, i.PrimaryRoleCode
FROM Relation.Individual AS i
    INNER JOIN Relation.Account AS acc ON i.AccountCode = acc.AccountNumber
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Relation.ContactDetail AS cd ON i.IndividualCode = cd.RelationCode
    INNER JOIN Relation.Address AS adr ON i.IndividualCode = adr.RelationCode
```

My question is about this statement:

```
(SELECT value FROM Relation.ContactDetail AS cd WHERE cd.ContactDetailTypeCode = 'EMAIL' AND cd.RelationCode = i.IndividualCode) AS Email,
```

Running this statement, will result in 1 row, but running it in the big query it results in 4 rows, it also shows records for the ContactTypes that are not EMAIL.

Does anyone know what i did wrong? :(

Answer (score 1):

A subquery in the place of a column after `select` has no impact on the number of rows returned.  If you replace the subquery with `'hello'`, you'll see that the query still returns 4 rows.

Look for the reason for the four rows in the `join` statements.  You can typically omit joins one by one to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a left join on the same table you perform the sub query on, but the left joins condition is missing the restriction: cd.ContactDetailTypeCode = 'EMAIL'

Adding this might solve your problem. Perhaps you could remove the sub query as well and just select the **value** from the joined table directly

```sql
SELECT i.PropertyCodeId, i.IndividualCode, i.LastName, 
   i.Firstname, i.AccountCode, acc.Name AS AccountName,
   cd.value AS Email,
   adr.City, adr.ZipCode, adr.StateCode, adr.CountryCode, 
   'undefined' AS MemberShipID, i.TierCode AS MemberShipTier,
   i.VipCode, i.Active, i.PrimaryRoleCode
FROM Relation.Individual AS i
INNER JOIN Relation.Account AS acc ON i.AccountCode = acc.AccountNumber
LEFT OUTER JOIN Relation.ContactDetail AS cd ON (i.IndividualCode = cd.RelationCode AND cd.ContactDetailTypeCode = 'EMAIL')
INNER JOIN Relation.Address AS adr ON i.IndividualCode = adr.RelationCode
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` returns more then one row your rows from the basic table (Relation.Individual) gets multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

> Running this statement, will result in 1 row, but running it in the big query it results in 4 rows, it also shows records for the **ContactTypes that are not EMAIL**.

Maybe it could be because you are doing a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on the wrong place, or that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should be a `INNER JOIN`.

If you use a `LEFT JOIN` pay attention to which table are on the both sides of the `LEFT JOIN`, because all rows of the left side table will be in the result set. Maybe you should set that `LEFT JOIN` the first.